# MKpolyline not visible at MKMapKit

Tags: mkmapview

I have a problem with my MKPolyline.

I have added this code but I see no line. I get the coordinates form a webserver with a http-request. I save the coordinates as a double and show with that my annotations.

in the viewcontroller.h

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) MKPolyline *routeLine; 
@property (nonatomic, retain) MKPolylineView *routeLineView;
```

in the viewcontroller.m

```
CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinateArray[7];
coordinateArray[0] = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(theCoordinate0.latitude, theCoordinate0.longitude);
coordinateArray[1] = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(theCoordinate1.latitude, theCoordinate1.longitude);
coordinateArray[2] = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(theCoordinate2.latitude, theCoordinate2.longitude);
coordinateArray[3] = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(theCoordinate3.latitude, theCoordinate3.longitude);
coordinateArray[4] = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(theCoordinate4.latitude, theCoordinate4.longitude);
coordinateArray[5] = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(theCoordinate5.latitude, theCoordinate5.longitude);
coordinateArray[6] = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(theCoordinate6.latitude, theCoordinate6.longitude);

self.routeLine = [MKPolyline polylineWithCoordinates:coordinateArray count:7];
[self.mapView setVisibleMapRect:[self.routeLine boundingMapRect]]; //If you want the route to be visible

[self.mapView addOverlay:self.routeLine];

-(MKOverlayView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForOverlay:(id<MKOverlay>)overlay
{
    if(overlay == self.routeLine)
    {
        if(nil == self.routeLineView)
        {
            self.routeLineView = [[[MKPolylineView alloc] initWithPolyline:self.routeLine]autorelease];
            self.routeLineView.fillColor = [UIColor redColor];
            self.routeLineView.strokeColor = [UIColor redColor];
            self.routeLineView.lineWidth = 10;

        }

        return self.routeLineView;
    }

    return nil;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you verified that your mapview is connected to the mapview on screen (the IBOutlet in Interface Builder)? the next thing to check is that you've set the delegate. Check this by putting a breakpoint or a debug statement in the `viewForOverlay` function.

P.S. with that code you're only ever going to be able to draw one line. It relies on `self.routeLine` and `self.routeLineView` and you only have one of each of those.